# GWT RPC on Tomcat giving error

Tags: gwt

I am trying to run my GWT application on tomcat , this GWT application runs perfectly on ocalhose , Works Fine on tomcat but just for client side , if i try calling rpc from tomcat it gives error

here is the attached error 
[image]

here is my web.xml class 
               
               http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
           version="2.5"
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

```
           <!-- Servlets -->

            <servlet>
          <servlet-name>DashBoardServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.dashboard.server.DashBoardServiceImpl</servlet-class>
      </servlet>

          <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>DashBoardServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/DashBoardServlet</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <!-- Default page to serve -->
       <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>DashBoardSupervisor.html</welcome-file>
       </welcome-file-list>

       </web-app>
```

here is RPC interface

```
            @RemoteServiceRelativePath("DashBoardServlet")
            public interface DashBoardService extends RemoteService {

ArrayList<FoundIntravue> fetchIntraVUE(String first, String second,  String choice);
String saveIntraVue(Intravue interVue, ArrayList<Networks> networksList) throws Exception;
String restoreDatabase(Date selectedDate) throws Exception;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`@RemoteServiceRelativePath`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RemoteServiceRelativePath.html)'s value is relative to your module base URL, so your GWT app calls `.../dashboardsupervisor/DashBoardServlet` (this is from your screenshot), but your `web.xml` maps the servlet to `/DashBoardServlet` instead of `/dashboardsupervisor/DashBoardServlet`.

Because there's nothing at `/dashboardsupervisor/DashBoardServlet`, Tomcat returns a 404; case made.

Comment: thanks for your help , my web.xml is now /dashboardsupervisor/DashBoardServlet  .but having the same error , my RPC is working fine if i run in eclipse without Tomcat,so i am doing something wrong in tomcat , if u can give some idea , thanks